# How to do something if text input is clicked when already focused - on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone

I'd like to perform an action when a text input is already focused. My current code is this:

```
$('.add_char_field .namefield').on("click", function(){
    if ($('.add_char_field .namefield').is(":focus")){
        MobileProfilePage.prototype.addCharacterScroll();
    }
});
```

This actually does work when I test this on Android devices! But it does not work for iPhone. Does anyone have a solution? Thanks.

I can refer to this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DtfYq/3/
Which someone put together in an answer for this similar question: [jQuery - do something if text input clicked when it already has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548626/jquery-do-something-if-text-input-clicked-when-it-already-has-focus)

However, if you have a way to check that jsfiddle on an iPhone, you will see that it does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: One way would be to keep track of whether it has focus or not yourself. Set a global `bool` every time the text box is clicked (or 'tabbed' to), and set the `bool` again on `blur`. That way you can keep the code you have there, but instead of checking `is(:"focus")`, just check your bool.

Comment: Just wondering, same result using instead: `if(document.getActiveElement === this)`???

Comment: Thanks, but again this doesn't seem to work on iPhone, however it does work elsewhere.

Comment: The problem isn't that it won't check if the field is focused - so using a boolean doesn't fix the problem. The click handler simply doesn't seem to work when the field is focused, no matter what check I use. If there are still any thoughts I'd appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this code to solve my problem:

```
$('.add_char_field .namefield').on("touchstart", function(){
    MobileProfilePage.prototype.addCharacterScroll();
})
```

Which is weird because I'm sure I tried "touchstart" prior to posting this question. Regardless, it works for both iPhone and Android devices.

Thanks everyone.